# AWS ELB SSL with GoDaddy UCC SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, https, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have purchased a GoDaddy Standard UCC SSL certicate for my main site www.example.com with the Subject Alternative Name: mail.example.com.

When I download, convert to PEM and update key, certificate and certificate chain into the AWS Console UI, the certificate is accepted.  BUT when I select it and assign to LoadBalancer it get an Error dialog:

"Failed to change listener SSL certificate: ValidationError"

There are no additional details other than "validation error".

Steps used to convert GoDaddy UCC SSL certificate for AWS ELB SSL.

1) Remove Passphrase from private key:

openssl rsa -in host.key -out host.nopassphrase.key

2) Convert GoDaddy certificate to PEM (not really needed since diff of two files are identical):

openssl x509 -in 123456789.crt -out host.pem -outform PEM

3) Log into AWS Console

4) Select EC2 Dashboard

5) Select Load Balancers under "Network & Security"

6) Select Load Balancer

7) Select Listeners tab

8) In SSL Certificate column, Select "(Change)"

The "Select Certificate" dialog box opens.

a) Select "Upload a new SSL Certificate" option

b) Enter Certificate name

c) Copy contents of host.nopassphrase.key and paste into "Private Key" text box

d) Copy contents of host.pem and paste into "Public Key Certificate" text box

e) Copy contents of gd_bundle.crt and paste into "Certificate Chain" text box

f) Click Save

Certificate name will appear in drop down under "Choose from your existing SSL Certificates"

g) Select Name and click Save.

Error Dialog:
Failed to change listener SSL certificate: ValidationError

I'm at a loss.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: RESOLVED: There must be a bug in AWS Management Console with UPDATING SSL Certificates.  If I REMOVE the ELB HTTPS Listener and add new with certificate, it worked!!!

Comment: I need to update the SSL certificates for an ELB on our AWS account. I have got the new certificates gd_bundle.crt and xxxxxxxx.crt files. I do not have the private key file which you referred as host.key above. Where do I get this file from ?